# Lie derivative in geometric algebra/Clifford algebra

Tags: exterior-algebra, clifford-algebras

What is the form of the Lie derivative in Clifford algebra?

Context:

Consider the Clifford algebra $\mathcal{C}l (p,q) $ with basis $\{e_i \}$.
The geometric derivative following Hestenes is defined as

$$
\nabla_x :=  e^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}
$$
(summation) where $\{e^i \}$ is the reciprocal basis and $x_i = x \cdot e^i$ for the radius-vector $x= x^i e_i$.

This paper http://math.columbia.edu/~dlitt/exposnotes/poincare_lemma.pdf 
defines the Lie derivative of a form $\omega$ as

$$  \mathcal{L}_x \omega = \iota_x \circ d \omega + d ( \iota_x \omega ) $$

Since in GA $$\nabla_x F =  \nabla_x \wedge F  + \nabla_x \cdot F $$ 
and there is a correspondence $ \nabla_x \wedge \sim d $

I would like to know what is the equivalent expression of the Lie derivative.

Comment: I'm interested in this as well, but I'm not sure that the Lie derivative is useful in GA. One of its most important properties is that it doesn't depend on a metric, or even a connection. I think $\nabla_x$ requires a connection. Still, you can define $\mathcal L$ by that same formula (Cartan's), using the left-contraction $$\iota_x\omega = x\;\lrcorner\;\omega$$ (This is the same as $x\cdot\omega$ except when $\omega$ is a scalar.)

Comment: Also, $d$ is equivalent to the cocurl, the tangential projection of the curl, not the curl itself.

Comment: Indeed $\nabla$ requires a metric. But the outer derivative does not.

Comment: In GA, the exterior derivative is defined in terms of $\nabla$.

Comment: What are you expecting for an "equivalent expression"? Is this sufficient $$\mathcal L_x\omega = x\,\lrcorner\,\big(P_\parallel(\nabla\wedge\omega)\big) + P_\parallel\big(\nabla\wedge(x\,\lrcorner\,\omega)\big)$$?

Comment: Interesting. Why do you add projections? By equivalent I mean "does the same job".

Comment: Consider a scalar function $f$ on the unit circle. Its derivative $\nabla f=\nabla\wedge f$ is a tangent vector. The curl of this vector, $\nabla\wedge(\nabla\wedge f)$ is a bivector in the circle's plane, not necessarily zero; but the exterior derivative has $ddf=0$ always. Thus $\nabla\wedge\neq d$; projection is necessary. See http://geocalc.clas.asu.edu/pdf/Shape%20in%20GC-2012.pdf , bottom of page 11/section 19.6

Comment: Hestenes defines a Lie derivative in "Spacetime Calculus for Gravitation Theory", section 12 ("Flows"). I don't know if it's equivalent to my definition. It uses a "gauge tensor", which I haven't studied. http://geocalc.clas.asu.edu/html/GCgravity.html

Comment: There's also the various Nijenhuis brackets. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schouten%E2%80%93Nijenhuis_bracket . This one is $$[A,B]=(A\,\llcorner\nabla)\wedge[B]-[A]\wedge(\nabla\lrcorner\, B)$$ where the brackets on the right indicate which factor is being differentiated by $\nabla$. For vectors, it simplifies to $$[a,b]=(a\cdot\nabla)b-(b\cdot\nabla)a.$$