# Are there higher order generalizations if the Lie derivative?

Tags: tensors, differential-forms, lie-derivative

Lie Brackets allow one to measure the derivative of a tensor field on manifolds, with respect to some vector field. Is there a generalization of this, where one could take a derivative with respect to say, a 2-form, or another tensor?

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but was curious and found the [Schouten–Nijenhuis bracket](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schouten%E2%80%93Nijenhuis_bracket) while looking around. See also the comment thread on [this question](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schouten%E2%80%93Nijenhuis_bracket). In particular the last comment by mr_e_man gives the expression (adapting notation slightly) $$[A, B] = (A\mathbin{\llcorner}\dot\nabla)\wedge\dot B - \dot A\wedge(\dot\nabla\lrcorner B).$$ This is for any multivector fields $A, B$...

Comment: ...This is in the context of a metric, which extends to multivectors via the left and right contractions $\lrcorner$ and $\llcorner$. The dots indicate what $\nabla$ is differentiating, and I believe that $\nabla$ is the gradient operator on the manifold.

Comment: Your two links are the same :)

Comment: Whoops! Here is what the second link should be: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2513769/lie-derivative-in-geometric-algebra-clifford-algebra